# Angular js ng style not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<span>Select color : </span>

<select ng-model="myStyle">
    <option value="">none</option>
    <option value="{color:red}">Red</option>
    <option value="{color:'green'}">Green</option>
</select>

<div ng-style="myStyle">
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/IOHjEGbuOzD4CjwRqIK9?p=preview

In this plunker, example 1 works perfectly fine but in example 2 select color is not working.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is actually a simple fix, have `myStyle` be more of a `myColor` type of declaration and on `ng-style` have your `{{'color':myColor}}` expression:

```
<select ng-model="myColor">
    <option value="">none</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>

<div ng-style="{'color':myColor}">
    <p>Text to change color</p>
</div>
```

There is no need for a `ng-change` function in *THIS* instance.

<kbd>[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jon23781/ZTnXV/7/)</kbd>

---

**Edit, explanation:**

Value in select option is not an angular directive so `myStyle` is being set to literally "{color:'red'}" not the Javascript `Object` `{"color":"red"}` that Angular is looking for and can parse in `ng-style`.

Since the literal value of "{color:'red'}" looks like the object then you will not notice the difference in batarang. But if you run a `console.log()` you'll see the difference.

Set your example one, then set example 2 to red and change your `clearFilter` function by adding the two logs and look at the output and you'll see what I mean:

```
$scope.clearFilter = function () {
    console.log('myStyle1', $scope.myStyle1);
    console.log('myStyle', $scope.myStyle);
    $scope.query = '';
    $scope.orderProp = '';
    $scope.myColor = '';
};
```

Comment: Thanks, i started with this approach only. In my example, in batarang myStyle was correctly set on change of select but still color was not changing in example 2.. can you tell me why ?

Answer (score 2):

for Angular 6, ngStyle can get working as follows

```
<p [ngStyle]="{'color': 'red'}"> I Read in Red</p>
```