# unable to change color using dropdown in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LeKmOgNkM2c0CyjB2U7z?p=preview) i am working on.now the problem is i am able to change color in exampple 1 but unable to change color in example 2.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular js ng style not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532635/angular-js-ng-style-not-working)

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a simple fix, have `myStyle` be more of a `myColor` type of declaration and on `ng-style` have your `{{'color':myColor}}` expression:

```
<select ng-model="myColor">
    <option value="">none</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
</select>

<div ng-style="{'color':myColor}">
    <p>Text to change color</p>
</div>
```

Here is a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/jon23781/ZTnXV/3/)

---

**Explanation:**

Value in select option is not an angular directive so `myStyle` is being set to literally "{color:'red'}" not the Javascript Object `{"color":"red"}` that Angular is looking for and can parse in `ng-style`.

Since the literal value of "{color:'red'}" looks like the object then you will not notice the difference in the Chrome AngularJS extension batarang. But if you run a `console.log()` you will see the difference.