# Having "ng-style" or "ng-attr-style" isn't generating in internet-explorer and safari but works fine in chrome

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, internet-explorer, dom

When i inspect the elements of my site in internet explorer and safari, the following code totally got vanished (didn't generate). but it works completely okay in chrome and firefox.

Using `ng-attr-style` doesn't work here(even in chrome). In chrome browser, it generates the code,(while inspecting) but it didn't work in front-end. In IE or Safari browser, the code didn't even generate (while inspecting).

have tried the following solutions but these solutions didn't bring any good https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

[AngularJS bug in IE with style vs ng-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36072798/angularjs-bug-in-ie-with-style-vs-ng-style)

[Angular -- Safari not displaying DOM properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47898276/angular-safari-not-displaying-dom-properly)

[Angular ng-style does not update in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517135/angular-ng-style-does-not-update-in-safari)

[Angular js ng style not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532635/angular-js-ng-style-not-working)

my code:

```
<div
    style="cursor: pointer;"
    title="{{ line.line.type == 'solid' ? 'Date: ' + vm.$filter('date')(vm.getDateFromSeconds(line.line.date)) : 'Current Date: ' +  vm.$filter('date')(vm.getDateFromSeconds(line.line.date)) }}&#13;{{ line.line.type == 'solid' ? 'Name: ' + line.line.name : undefined }}"
    class="eventLines {{'type-'+line.line.type}}"
    ng-repeat="line in col.eventLine track by $index"
    ng-style="{{line.styleCss}}">
    <div 
        class="lineSquare" 
        ng-show="outerIndex==1" 
        ng-style="{'background':line.line.color}">
    </div>
</div>
```

generated output (Actually Desired) in chrome:

```
<div 
    style="cursor: pointer; position: absolute; z-index: 1; height: 50px; width: 2px; left: 46.0161px; border-left: 2px dashed rgb(75, 78, 83);" 
    title="Current Date: Aug 5, 2019" 
    class="eventLines type-dashed" 
    ng-repeat="line in col.eventLine track by $index" 
    ng-style="{&quot;position&quot;:&quot;absolute&quot;,&quot;z-index&quot;:1,&quot;height&quot;:&quot;50px&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:&quot;2px&quot;,&quot;left&quot;:&quot;46.59677419354839px&quot;,&quot;border-left&quot;:&quot;2px dashed #4B4E53&quot;}">
        <div 
            class="lineSquare ng-hide" 
            ng-show="outerIndex==1" 
            ng-style="{background:line.line.color}" 
            aria-hidden="true" 
            style="background: rgb(75, 78, 83);">
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the source value behind "line.line.color"? Is is "rgb(75, 78, 83);" or some HEX value?

Comment: @MikeVranckx yes that is a rgb value.

Comment: Try using directly background-color property, ng-style="{ 'background-color': line.line.color }